# Clients could not join to domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, internal-dns

When I`m trying join a client to the domain controller the client raises the following error:

> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "amf.local":
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
>   (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.amf.local
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:
>
> 192.168.1.3
>
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:
>
> amf.local
>   local
>   . (the root zone)

I have faced with this error for several days after Windows server 2012 R2 update.
I am not sure there was due to the update, So I've googled a lot and I think my dns server is not working properly because I can not see my domain with `nslookup amf.local` and unfortunately I can not find where is the issue and how to fix it!
I have tested following solutions before:

- Reinstall DNS server
- Set manual DNS server ip address on client side (my server:192.168.1.3)
- Ipconfig/release,flushdns,renew,registerdns on both client and server
- Adding client ip (192.168.1.11) to dns server manually
- Checking to have same client and server date and time settings
- Reset Netlogon service on both client and server side

But the problem is still unresolved.
I honestly ask for help from those with the same experience.

Comment: Read https://serverfault.com/questions/660778/server-2012-r2-active-directory-domain-srv-dns-records-suddenly-disappeared

Comment: Thanks for your link but I couldn't resolve the problem with its directions!...